# What is the maximum resolution for a second monitor attached to a MBP Retina?

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I'm curious if my new machine will support (for example) 3840x2400 retina-quality external monitor in additional to the built-in screen or whether that will exceed the capacity of the video card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Tech Specs page over at Apple](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-retina/):

13":

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up to two external displays, at millions of colors

15":

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up to two external displays, at millions of colors

Comment: So for the 15" it can effectively support 2x2560x1600 or 8 million additional pixels... I guess I'll have to go with 2 smaller but hi-res monitors...

Comment: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/ may also be something to look into if you just need a ton of space.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any direct experience with this so YMMV, but some research suggests that the maximum supported total resolution of Thunderbolt is 3840 x 2400 WQUXGA @ 60Hz.

In regards to the graphics card question, it is unlikely your graphics card will be substantially stressed unless you are pushing a videogame.  Working in the UI and document editing should be fine.

[Reference](https://superuser.com/questions/441395/what-is-the-maximum-resolution-that-a-thunderbolt-monitor-can-display)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @da4! Apple have updated that page now:

**HDMI video output**

- Support for 1080p resolution at up to 60Hz
- Support for 3840-by-2160 resolution at 30Hz
- Support for 4096-by-2160 resolution at 24Hz

So I can have one external 4k monitor at 30Hz - certainly good enough for programming.